# Why can I add a new topic but I can't add new comments to the SQLite database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sqlite, mustache

I am working on a forum app and I want users to be able to post their own comments per topic. So I have been able to create, post, and display new topics but when I try and create a new comment, it will post but won't display except the two comments I have in my schema file. I have spent aoptll week trying to fiqure this out and now is the time I need some serious help.

```
var express = require('express');
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
var fs = require('fs');
var Mustache = require ('mustache');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

var db = new sqlite3.Database('./forum.db');
var app = express();

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send(fs.readFileSync('./views/topics/index.html', 'utf8'));

});
app.get('/topics', function(req,res) {
    var template = fs.readFileSync('./views/topics/topics.html', 'utf8');

    db.all("SELECT * FROM topics;", function(err, topics){
        var html = Mustache.render(template, {listoftopics: topics});
        res.send(html);
    });
});


app.get('/topics/new',  function(req, res){
    res.send(fs.readFileSync('./views/topics/new.html', 'utf8'));

});

app.post('/topics/new', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    db.run("INSERT INTO topics(title, creator, date, body) VALUES ('" + req.body.title + "','" + req.body.creator + "','" + req.body.date + "','" + req.body.body + "')");
    res.redirect("/topics")
});





app.get('/comments/new', function(req, res){
    res.send(fs.readFileSync('./views/comments/newComment.html', 'utf8'));
});


app.post('/comments/new', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body)
    db.run("INSERT INTO comments(person_created, input) VALUES ('" + req.body.person_created + "','" + req.body.input + "')");
    res.redirect("/topics/")

});




app.get('/topics/:id', function(req, res){
var id = req.params.id;
res.locals.id = id



    db.all("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE id = " + id + ";", {}, function(err, topic){
        console.log(topic)

        var body = topic.body;

        db.all("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE topic_id = " + id + ";", {}, function(err, comment){

        var person_created = comment.person_created;
        var input = comment.input


        fs.readFile('./views/topics/show.html', 'utf8', function(err, html){
            var renderedHTML = Mustache.render(html, {body:topic, person_created:comment, input:comment});
            res.send(renderedHTML);
            console.log(comment);

        });
        });
    });
});


app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("LISTENING!");
});
```

My schema file

```
var sqlite3 = require ('sqlite3');
var db = new sqlite3.Database('./forum.db');


db.serialize(function(){
    db.run("CREATE TABLE topics(id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, title varchar, creator varchar, date varchar, body varchar);")
    db.run("CREATE TABLE comments(person_created varchar, input varchar, topic_id integer, FOREIGN KEY (topic_id) references topics(id));")

db.parallelize(function(){
    db.run("INSERT INTO topics(title, creator, date, body) VALUES ('Top R&B Hits of the 80s', 'Michael', '4/15/15', 'Please share some of your favorite R&B Hits from the decade!' );")
    db.run("INSERT INTO comments(person_created, input, topic_id) VALUES ('Sheila', 'Bille Jean by Michael Jackson', 1);")
    db.run("INSERT INTO comments(person_created, input, topic_id) VALUES ('George ', 'Gett Outta of My Dreams by Billy Ocean', 1); ")
})
})
```

Show page for new comments

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    background-image: url("http://blog.paradizo.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/nyc-empire-room.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% auto;

}


</style>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Topic ID</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>

{{#body}}
<h1>{{body}}</h1>
{{/body}}


<h2>Comments<h2>

<h3>
<ol>
{{#person_created}}
<li>
{{person_created}} - {{input}}

</li>
{{/person_created}}
</ol>
</h3>







<form action="/comments/new" method='GET'>
<button>Create New Comment</button>
</form>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML including the forms used to submit the comment?

Comment: Yes but no new comments are shown. In my terminal, it will show the input via console.log but no topic_id.

Comment: Can you add the HTML you are using to submit the form to your post?

Comment: What do you mean add? Are you saying can I add new comments to the html?

Comment: Is this what you are using to submit comments? `<form action="/comments/new" method='GET'>
<button>Create New Comment</button>
</form>`

Comment: Yes. I have topics setup that same way using topics/new so I figured that's how  adding new comments should be

Answer (score 0):

Hey Mike I noticed in your route comments/new you perform an sql query that might be the issue.

`db.run("INSERT INTO comments(person_created, input) VALUES ('" + req.body.person_created + "','" + req.body.input + "')");`

I believe it should be `db.run("INSERT INTO comments(person_created, input, topic_id) VALUES ('" + req.body.person_created + "','" + req.body.input + "')");`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but unfortunately it didn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your `form` should use the `POST` method for submitting comments in order to trigger the proper `router` for the `/comments/new` URL. You need to also submit the required `input` fields required in your router as part of the form to expose them in the `req.body` array.

```
<form action="/comments/new" method='POST'>
   <input type="text" value="person_created">
   <input type="text" value="input">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This will allow you to properly trigger the relevant router on submission of the form. The `req.body` data arrow will then be passed through the router and you can use it to add the comment to thee database as you currently have it setup.

Comment: I checked my terminal and this is what I get via console `{ person_created: 'Mike', input: 'Test' }` but still doesn't post to HTML. 

This is the query I have now

       `app.post('/comments/new', function(req, res){
 console.log(req.body)
 db.run("INSERT INTO comments(person_created, input, topic_id) VALUES ('" + req.body.person_created + "','" + req.body.input + "', '" + req.body.topic_id + "')");
 res.redirect("/topics/")

});`

Comment: `<input type="text" value="person_created">` doesn't work because it has the name of the values inside the input areas and I have to type over them. I have `name='person_created'` instead

Comment: I just checked my comments table in sqlite and it does add new comments but not to the html. In sqlite it shows:

`sqlite> SELECT * FROM COMMENTS;
Sheila|Billie Jean by Michael Jackson|1
George |Get Outta of My Dreams by Billy Ocean|1
Mike|Test|undefined`

Comment: It looks like you are setting your local variables for the comments here: `var renderedHTML = Mustache.render(html, {body:topic, person_created:comment, input:comment});`. You may want to verify the contents of your `comment` variable. Note that you are setting `person_created` and `input` to the exact same value as local variables for rendering in your HTML.

Comment: I don't understand it. How do I verify?

Comment: You are sending the comments of both `person_created` and `input` to `comment`. You should verify that `comment` contains the correct information, or else it will not display on your HTML page. If it does not then you need to modify your SQL query to return the correct results since you already verified that the correct information is in the SQL database after posting a comment.

Comment: When I submit a new comment, when I checked the terminal it looks like it accepts it  `{ person_created: 'Mike', input: 'Test' }`

Comment: Right, so now you need to verify that on your router that is displaying the HTML page that your query against the database is returning the correct results and setting them to the local variables that you are using to display the comments.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you read the documentation for Node.js/Express APIs on the interactions of routers/views/databases to strengthen your understandings.

Comment: Thanks I will. What would be the best way to verify?

Comment: Just use `console.log` statements before you set your local variables for displaying them in your HTML.